# Copy from excel to URL

Tags: applescript, ms-office

I'm doing my first applescript. I want to copy a short text (that's a website) from excel into the Pingdom Tools Speed Test. In the long run I want it to do it with a lot of different texts - but first I want to start with one.

I managed to open Excel, and then the document. But then I have to copy for example field B1. I managed to 'goto' B1, but then I have to copy it, and I can't figure out how.

The next sted is to activate chrome and then tools.pingdom.com - I'm able to do that. But how can I then paste the value of B1 into the field in Pingdom?

I hope someone can help me. If it's not explained good enough, let me know.

Best,
Soren

Comment: Please can you clarify what you are doing? It is hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. You write `I want to copy a short text (that's a website)`.. when you write website, do you mean URL (something like `https://apple.stackexchange.com`)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Microsoft excel so I cannot really help with setting a variable in an AppleScript with the information from Field B1.  This following code may help you a bit and set you on the right track.

```
property theURL : "https://tools.pingdom.com/"
-- change the URL in the following variable to the URL from field B1 from Excel
set urlFromExcel to "https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338936/copy-from-excel-to-url"

if application "Google Chrome" is not running then
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        activate
        repeat while not (exists of window 1)
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
        tell its window 1
            set URL of (make new tab) to theURL
        end tell
    end tell
else if application "Google Chrome" is running then
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        if not (exists of (tabs of window 1 whose URL contains "pingdom")) then
            tell its window 1
                set URL of (make new tab) to theURL
            end tell
        end if
    end tell
end if

tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of window 1
    repeat while loading is true
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
end tell

inputByID("urlInput", urlFromExcel)

to inputByID(theId, theValue)
    tell application "Google Chrome" to (tabs of window 1 whose URL contains "pingdom")
    set pingdomTabs to item 1 of the result
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        execute pingdomTabs javascript "document.getElementById('" & theId & "').value ='" & theValue & "';"
    end tell
end inputByID
```

[image]